# Como faço para converter esse Objeto

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como converter o objeto:

```
[ { company: ["5dc317a826bc467c9ca8054e", "5e53f7d32b422507c4dcb11d" ] } ]
```

para `["5dc317a826bc467c9ca8054e", "5e53f7d32b422507c4dcb11d"]` em Node.js.

Comment: Você poderia acrescentar mais detalhes à pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível "converter" esse objeto da forma que você pensando, mas é possível obter o resultado que deseja obtendo o valor do atributo `company` dessa forma:

```js
const objeto = [{company: ["5dc317a826bc467c9ca8054e", "5e53f7d32b422507c4dcb11d"]}];

const array = objeto[0].company;
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, valeu deu certo!